# Bootstrap Nav Bar Responsive

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with the Bootstrap 4 navbar. I'm not able to close the it back when `<a>` inside the `<li>` tag is clicked.

When I used `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"`
inside the `<a>` tag it works, but the tag `<a href=''>` does not follow the link.

Tried Using jQuery to target the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>`, but it doesn't work as well. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">

    <span class="navbar-text">&nbsp;</span>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse hide" id="navbarMenu">                     
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#sec-1" class="nav-link">link 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#sec-2" class="nav-link">link 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#sec-3" class="nav-link">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
    $('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about following the link via `javascript` once it has been clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-nav>li>a', function(event){
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    window.location.href = $(event.currentTarget).attr('href');
});
```

Here a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euo0cag4/1/) based on the above example.

Comment: Worked Perfect, Thanks a Lot.